# Error while adding AddOptions in Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to implement options pattern as mentioned in this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#options-example

When I add these 2 lines in ConfigureServices of Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Setup options with DI
        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<AppSettingsModel>(Configuration);
```

I get below call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties error-
[call is ambiguous error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJL3e.png)

My complete project.json is like this-

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Glimpse": "2.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

My environment is - VS2015 update3, .net core SDK 1.0.0 and preview2 tooling

My project template is - ASP.NET core application (.NET framework 4.6.1)

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: Remove dependency on `Glimpse`, its not supporting ASP:NET Core 1.0 RTM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `Glimpse` from your dependencies. As you can see on [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse/2.0.0-beta1) it depends on `Glimpse.Server` and `Glimpse.Server` [depends](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Server/) on `Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Embedded` which is an outdated package of ASP.NET Core until the RC1 version. The packages are now named `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*`.

This causes that both (old and new assemblies) get fetched and the compiler can't determine which one to use. Mixing versions is always very bad.

Comment: Awesome... thanks did fixed it :) But how did figure out in 2mins?

Comment: @hoc439: The error description only happens, when two libraries conflicts in a method and this happened quite often from the switch of rc1 to rc2. All other packages looked fine in your project.json, so ha short lookup at Nuget for glimpse confirms it