# Error while adding AddOptions in Program.cs

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen this post, but the error is different than mine.

[Error while adding AddOptions in Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565120/error-while-adding-addoptions-in-startup-cs)

My Error is this:

> 'ServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddOptions' and no extension method 'AddOptions' accepting a first argument of type 'ServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

My code is this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static IServiceProvider svcProvider = null;

private static void LoadDIStartup()
{
    //Dependency Injection Setup Start
    var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT");
    Console.WriteLine("ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT: {0}", env);
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
        .Build();


    svcProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddOptions()
        .Configure<AppConfig>(configuration.GetSection("AppConfig"))
        .AddConfigFile()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    IgniteDependencyResolver.SetProvider(svcProvider);
    IgniteDependencyResolver.SetConfiguration(configuration);
    IgniteDependencyResolver.Bind<AppConfig>();
    //Dependency Injection Setup End

}
```

My package config is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="BouncyCastle" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="MailKit" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="MimeKit" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.7.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

EDIT:

Added the using statement above. It was there but I missed when copying it.

Comment: You are missing a using directive.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I added it. It was there. Anything else missing?

Comment: I think you need more usings I don't think those are the right ones. If you click on the Quick Fix in the IDE it should prompt you to import the right ones. Obviously, you can also search for the method online and see where it is defined.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I did that but IDE didn't prompt me any fixes.

Comment: Just search for add options you'll find it in the docs and see where the namespace that defines it is

Comment: @AluanHaddad Found it. Microsoft.Extensions.Options is the missing one. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers